# how to add methods in controller file in joomla 3.4

Tags: joomla

I am trying to work with controller file in joomla 3.4. Tell me what is the differences for connecting model and views in joomla 3.4 to joomla 2.5

Answer (score 0):

operation code available in the model and out-put display in view part and model function  control in the controller.same step effort in joomla 3.5 and joomla 2.5